# Display cell table data in a TextView using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, css, jsoup

I want to display in a `TextView` the Snow in the past 24 hours of a ski resort. I used the CSS path and tried other ways but nothing happens the `TextView` doesn't display nothing.

The web page: http://www.arizonasnowbowl.com/resort/snow_report.php

The CSS path:  #container > div.right > table.interior > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.infoalt

```
private class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String desc;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Snowreport.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Snow Report");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements elms = document.select("td.infoalt");
            for(Element e:elms)
                if(e.className().trim().equals("infoalt"))
                //^^^<--trim is required as,
                // their can be leading and trailing space
                {

                    TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.snowp24);
                    txtdesc.setText((CharSequence) e);


                }



            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
Element div = doc.getElementById("contentinterior");
Elements tables = div.getElementsByTag("table");
Element table = tables.get(1);

String mSnow = table.getElementsByTag("tr").get(1).getElementsByTag("td").get(1).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have the incorrect `String` for the selection parameter. The correct selection to use as a parameter for `Document.select()` can be found by 'Inspecting the element' of a webpage most easily done by right clicking in the Chrome browser.

The following code may produce a better result for you:

```
final Elements tableElements = response.parse()
                    .getElementsByClass("info")
                    .select("td");

for (Element element : tableElements) {

    String string = element.getElementsByClass("infoalt").text().trim()

    Log.d("Jsoup", string);

}
```

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: You need to add a Jsoup Response before the above code. final Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(mUrl).method(Connection.Method.POST) .timeout(10000) .execute();